# Moment.js works weirdly

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using Moment to work with time and what I wanted to achieve is to convert local time to UTC time. My local time is GMT+5.

So, here is my code:

```js
moment("12:15", "HH a").utc().format("HH")
```

What I expect to get is `19` but I get `07`. I really need your help. I am using moment.js 2.24.0.

Comment: 07:15 GMT+0 is 12:15 GMT+5 — this is working correctly.

Comment: If you are at +5 why do expect 19 and not 7? Utc id +0, so 5 hours less.

Comment: @coll, I mean 12:15 is AM and take 5 hours out then 19 would be the right number? right?

Comment: @RaniSharim, I mean 12:15 is AM therefore if we take out 5 hours then 19 would be the right one. Right?

Comment: @qweeee `HH` is 24 hour time

Comment: @qweeee You need to reduce 5 to get to utc. and even if we used your logic , we'd get 17 not 19.

Comment: @coll, then how can I modify the code so that it works accordingly?

Comment: @qweeee reference the documentation https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Answer (score 0):

Use `hh` to parse the input hours and don't forget the minutes.

```js
console.log(moment('12:15', 'hh:mm').utc().format('HH'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Since Moment is EOL, you should use Luxon instead.

```js
const { DateTime } = luxon;

console.log(DateTime.fromFormat('12:15', 'hh:mm').toUTC().toFormat('HH'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.0.2/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but still I get 07 but I think logical to get 19. Please can you check out http://jsfiddle.net/vw81bhsq/43/ in there I get 19 why? just bearing in mind my GMT+5 timezone

Comment: @qweeee Your JSFiddle is the same as your example. You need to correctly PARSE first. That is your main issue.

Comment: @qweeee There is `a` in format string which indicates am or pm. Since your input time `12:15` doesn't have such indicator, moment probably thinks your date at `am`. For GMT +5, you subtract 5 hours to find the time in UTC which means 24 - 5 = 19. `HH` is the 24 hour format so, you see 19.